# Dynamic height of UITableView with constraints

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, storyboard

I want to make an interface in Storyboard which scales automatically for all iPhone screen sizes as shown in the picture below:

[image: View in XCode Storyboard]

What I want is for view 1 and view 2 to have a constant height, but cover equally much of the horizontal space, and for the UITableView below to stretch all the way up to the UIViews. How can I specify constraints to achieve this effect?

I know how to do this programatically, but I have made it sort of a goal to learn storyboard in this project.

Anybody have any tips?

Answer (score 0):

If you want view1 and view2 to remain fixed at the top, that’s easy enough to do by constraining view1.bottom == tableView.top.

If you want view1 and view2 to scroll with the table view, then put them inside the table view’s header. (To make a header, drag a generic UIView to the space just above the prototype cells in the storyboard editor.) I don’t recommend using constraints to try to make something outside the table view scroll with it, even though that’s (sometimes) possible.

Control-drag from view1 to view2 and create an “equal widths” constraint to divide the space equally.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was able to do the "equal widhts" easily. However to dynamically make the two share all available horizontal space was not done with the same constraint. Do I need to add another one?

Comment: You’ll need to constrain them to the edges of their parents, i.e. left of view1 to parent left, right of view2 to parent right.